# Where to set variableObservable for refresh value of nested widget using Obx Getx Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-getx

I'm trying to refresh value of nested widget using Obx Getx flutter. but whenever i try to refresh the value of nested widget they gives me error.

[image: error which is comes when i try to wrap widget with Obx]

here is my code of widget.
[image: code of wrap widget with Obx]

I'm trying to refresh value of postActivitybuttons().

```
Widget postActivityButtons(
  BuildContext context, {
  int **smileCount** = 0,
}) {
  return Row(
    children: [
        child: Row(
          children: [
            **smileCount** != 0
                ? Padding(
                    padding: paddingOnly(left: 10.0),
                    child: labels(
                      text: numeral(**smileCount**),
                    ),
                  )
                : const SizedBox(),
```

i was tryint to refresh smileCount using Obx.(with nested widget)

I was try to put Obx with different places. but they still give me error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your variable as observable in order to use `ObX`.

You can consider this snippet.

```js
Widget postActivityButtons(
  BuildContext context, {
  Rx<int> smileCount = 0.obs,
}) {
  return Row(
    children: [
          Obx(()=>
        child: Row(
          children: [
            smileCount.value != 0
                ? Padding(
                    padding: paddingOnly(left: 10.0),
                    child: labels(
                      text: numeral(smileCount.value),
                    ),
                  )
                : const SizedBox(),
               ],
             ),
```

Comment: Still not working.
they send me same error..

Comment: Could you please put the full code of the controller and the view file ?